# Delay appearance on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to achieve an effect like on this website: http://pollenlondon.com/antiques-boutiques/ 
I got a prallax effect to work but I cannot figure out how to delay the showing up of the content a little bit. I am searching for a solution, which does not depend on a plugin, like skrollr.
The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1kj1j63o/4/ 
HTML

```
<section class="module content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Some text</h2>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
    <div class="wrapper">   
    </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
</section>

<section class="module content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>This part is supposed to show up with an effect</h2>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section.module.content {
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
    min-height: 600px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
section.module.content.parallax {
    height: 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

section.module.content.parallax-1 {
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url('https://ununsplash.imgix.net/uploads/141319062591093cefc09/ad50c1f0?q=75&fm=jpg&s=a356dd61ff3da2269124bcd12a303b7e');
}

.wrapper-effect {
    display: none;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('.wrapper-effect').scrollTop(300px).css("display":"block");
});
```

I am really new to this and would be very happy for any kind of help!!

Comment: you'd need a bit of javacript to achieve it. But I don't see any javascript in your question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hint: use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)

Comment: No, I did not try anything because I cannot write javascript!

Comment: lol :p in that case, learn javascript! or use a plugin, like skrollr ;) Or hire a javascript developer...

Comment: The scrollTop() method sets or returns the vertical scrollbar position for the selected elements. Does that mean I could use a certain scroll position at which the elemts appear?

Comment: yup, or use the scroll position relative to the element's position, using [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) in example. Do something like: `if (scrolltop > (element.offset().y - 200)) { // move element up }` ( <- pseudo code doesn't work out of the box ;))

Comment: I updated my question and the fiddle. Could you help me out a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this website: http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/scrolling.html

Here are the instructions from that site on how to animate an object on scroll:

Add jQuery to the `<head>` element of your webpage:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Add this before the `</body>` tag to trigger the animation when the user scrolls to the element:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.wrapper').each(function(){
        var pos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (pos < topOfWindow+400) {
                $(this).addClass("slideUp");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Replace `.wrapper` with the ID or class of the element you want animated.
Replace slideUp with an animation class.

400 represents the space between the element and the top of the screen. The animation activates when the element is 400px from the top of the screen. Increase this number to make the animaton activate sooner.

Here's the slideUp class (also from that website):

```
.slideUp{
animation-name: slideUp;
-webkit-animation-name: slideUp;    

animation-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

animation-timing-function: ease;    
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

visibility: visible !important;
}
@keyframes slideUp {
0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
50%{
    transform: translateY(-8%);
}
65%{
    transform: translateY(4%);
}
80%{
    transform: translateY(-4%);
}
95%{
    transform: translateY(2%);
}           
100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
}
50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8%);
}
65%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4%);
}
80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
}
95%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2%);
}           
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
}   
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5gjwm3v/ (this example uses a timer instead of scroll for simplicity)

Comment: Sure thing! Here it is implemented with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1kj1j63o/5/ important thing to note: use visibility: hidden here instead of display: none, though you might be able to mess with the code to use display instead if you prefer that for some reason

Comment: You should ask money for this Joe ;)